# Javascript createTextNode doesn't work

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, createtextnode

I have an assignment at my school to write the DOM of the webpage when JavaScript has executed. We got the assignment on paper and when I tried to write it on sublime and run it the code won't work. I think the problem is 
at the following lines:

```
tdTextNodeRef=document.createTextNode(codeNodeRefs[counter].innerHTML);
        tdNodeRef.appendChild(tdTextNodeRef);
```

The full code can be found here: https://github.com/Nirakander/JS-assignment

Why won't this work? Really bad assignment when the code is not even working. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you think that's not working? There is also `tableNodeRef.appendChild(trNodeRef);`, which is not liked by IE as it wants to add rows to a *tbody*, not directly to a table.

Comment: The console says "cannot read property of 'innerHTML' of undefined" so thats why I think that's the problem. What do you mean by tbody? When I run the code it looks like tableNodeRef appends a tr to a table?

Answer (score 2):

Your error is here:

```
for(var counter=0; counter<codeNodeRefs.length; counter++);{
----------------------------------------------------------^
```

That extra semicolon ends the if statement with an empty block, the following block is seen as just a block of statements. So it loops around twice, does nothing, then goes into the block.

When entering that block, *count* is *codeNodeRefs.length* (i.e. 2), so *codeNodeRefs[counter]* returns *undefined*.

Just remove the semicolon.